# macro hangs power query add-in in activated

Tags: excel, vba, 32-bit

I have Excel 2010/32bit VBA macro that run on scheduled task on win10 (64bit) pro. When I ran it on win7 (32bit) I had Just-In-Time (JIT) error

Cannot cast null to type 'System.Double'

> Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Com.ComWrapperException: Cannot cast null to type 'System.Double'. System.NullReferenceException

What should I do to prevent it?

Comment: Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Com.ComWrapperException: Cannot cast null to type 'System.Double'. System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Please correct the invalid tag.

Comment: Please show the (relevant) VBA code you are using and tell in which line you get the error. Also see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I think i have to learn more about how to ask.

Comment: My macro have no problem in win10 pro,but hangs on win7.I will learn how to show you my code and errors.Thanks